# SharePoint Quick Launch Navigational Structure Error

Tags: navigation, quick-launch

I recently removed a task list from "Site Contents" BEFORE I removed the link from the quick launch. Now I receive the following error whenever I try to add, remove, or rearrange quick launch items. Is there a way I can recreate the quick launch without having to start from scratch?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a month but the issue seems to have fixed itself. I'm not sure what happened behind the scenes that resolved this issue but I'm not complaining :)